# Java Exception When Executing `spark-shell` Command

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using `spark-shell` to launch Spark using Scala, but I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
      at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
  ... 47 elided
```

Comment: You've cut the most important part of stacktrace

Comment: Or more importantly you need to work out how to see the rest of the stack trace - I think the tool cut most of the stack trace.  If you do that then you'll probably see the problem yourself.

Comment: Can you update the question with the spark and scala versions?